# Python matplotlib animate a candlestick plot

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I've been trying to find a way to use the animate function with candlestick data.  With most examples I've seen the class needs a generator function to return pyplot objects, but how do I do this with a candlestick?

Here's an example of an animation I made that updates the plot each time it is called.  I would like to change it to use an animation, but I've been having trouble figuring out how to do this.

```
import time
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, epoch2num, num2epoch, MinuteLocator
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick

class Chart3(object):
    def __init__(self,testData, maxt=10):
        self.maxt=maxt
        self.testData=testData
        self.result=testData[:self.maxt]
        self.dataCount=0

        self.tdata=[r[0] for r in self.result]
        self.sdata=[r[4] for r in self.result]
        self.mdata=[r[3] for r in self.result]

        # plot the data
        xfmt = DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
        self.ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
        self.plot()

    def plot(self):
        if len(self.tdata) > self.maxt: # roll the arrays
            self.tdata = self.tdata[-self.maxt:]
            self.sdata = self.sdata[-self.maxt:]
            self.mdata = self.mdata[-self.maxt:]
            self.result = self.result[-self.maxt:]

        self.lineMin = Line2D(self.tdata, self.sdata, color='r')
        self.ax.add_line(self.lineMin)
        self.lineMax = Line2D(self.tdata, self.mdata, color='g')
        self.ax.add_line(self.lineMax)

        candlestick(self.ax, self.result, width=60 / 86400.0,  colorup='g', colordown='r')
        self.ax.xaxis_date()
        if len(self.tdata) > 1:
            self.ax.set_xlim(self.tdata[0], self.tdata[-1])
        self.ax.set_ylim(min(self.sdata) * 0.99, max(self.mdata) * 1.01)
        self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()

        plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, horizontalalignment='center')
        plt.show(block=False)

    def updatePrices(self):
        '''
        adds a data point from testData to result list for plotting
        @return:
        '''
        self.dataCount+=1
        results=self.testData[self.maxt+self.dataCount] # add another point of data
        t=(results[0])
        if self.tdata[-1]!=t:
            trade=results
            self.result.append([t, trade[1], trade[2], trade[3], trade[4],
                           trade[5], trade[6]])
            self.tdata.append(self.result[-1][0])
            self.sdata.append(self.result[-1][4])
            self.mdata.append(self.result[-1][3])

        self.plot()

    def animate(self):
        ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, frames=self.updatePrices, interval=1000, blit=True)
        plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    testData=[[735265.79166666663, 21.901, 21.901, 21.901, 21.901, 21.901, 0],
[735265.79236111115, 21.901, 21.901, 21.901, 21.901, 21.901, 0],
[735265.79305555555, 21.901, 21.901, 21.901, 21.901, 21.901, 0],
[735265.79374999995, 21.9, 21.901, 21.901, 21.9, 21.9005, 11.65],
[735265.79444444447, 21.901, 21.939, 21.939, 21.901, 21.91525, 23.23606],
[735265.79513888888, 21.94, 21.95, 21.9703, 21.94, 21.953781250000002, 172.91374199999998],
[735265.79583333328, 21.96, 21.99, 21.99, 21.96, 21.973333333333336, 142.974981],
[735265.7965277778, 21.995, 21.995, 21.997, 21.995, 21.995533333333338, 36.541180000000004],
[735265.7972222222, 21.9703, 21.995, 22.0, 21.9703, 21.993162500000004, 18.305711],
[735265.79791666672, 21.9999, 21.86, 22.0, 21.86, 21.93492, 103.2468273],
[735265.79861111112, 21.9045, 21.9045, 21.9045, 21.9045, 21.9045, 2.43879],
[735265.79930555553, 21.929, 21.861, 21.99, 21.86, 21.92566666666666, 2.838343],
[735265.80000000005, 21.9241, 21.899, 21.9241, 21.899, 21.907366666666665, 10.0],
[735265.80069444445, 21.861, 21.86, 21.861, 21.86, 21.860888888888887, 111.367172],
[735265.80138888885, 21.86, 21.861, 21.861, 21.86, 21.8604, 78.36582],
[735265.80208333337, 21.861, 21.862, 21.862, 21.859, 21.860483333333335, 112.842532],
[735265.80277777778, 21.862, 21.863, 21.88, 21.862, 21.8694, 83.64361899999999],
[735265.80347222218, 21.88, 21.88, 21.88, 21.88, 21.88, 7.46027],
[735265.8041666667, 21.88, 21.9256, 21.9256, 21.88, 21.9104, 7.06897],
[735265.8048611111, 21.9256, 21.9256, 21.9256, 21.9256, 21.9256, 0.339032],
[735265.8055555555, 21.9256, 21.9256, 21.9256, 21.9256, 21.9256, 2.024438],
[735265.80625000002, 21.88, 21.88, 21.881, 21.88, 21.880249999999997, 25.00003],
[735265.80694444443, 21.92, 21.92, 21.92, 21.92, 21.92, 0],
[735265.80763888895, 21.92, 21.92, 21.92, 21.92, 21.92, 0],
[735265.80833333335, 21.91, 21.92, 21.92, 21.91, 21.915, 80.0],
[735265.80902777775, 21.881, 21.92, 21.92, 21.881, 21.907, 43.913890200000004],
[735265.80972222227, 21.914, 22.0, 22.0, 21.914, 21.973115625, 368.000066],
[735265.81041666667, 21.93, 21.93, 21.93, 21.93, 21.93, 0],
[735265.81111111108, 21.9, 21.93, 21.93, 21.9, 21.9225, 15.475088999999999],
[735265.8118055556, 21.93, 22.0, 22.0, 21.91, 21.97401, 56.620048589999996]
]

    chart=Chart3(testData)
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)
        chart.updatePrices()
```

Right now this example charts 10 points from the test data, and each time updatePrice is called it moves the data one step in time until the data runs out.  I would prefer to setup a aninamation and call the updatePrice and eliminate the need to loop through updatePrice.  The animation method I tried to create isn't correct, and while I can use:

```
self.lineMin.set_data(self.tdata, self.sdata)
self.lineMax.set_data(self.tdata, self.mdata)
```

To generate data for the FuncAnimate, I don't know how to pass back the new candle data.  How would I modify this example to use animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user6972, please see the attached code for a complete resolution to your question.  This was tested on Windows 7 with WinPython x64 2.7.6.2.  I updated your code a bit with some restructuring, removal of unused/redundant elements, comments, and [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) compliance.  Please restructure to suit your own needs.

Here are some notes on the updates made:

1. I believe the main issue you were having is that the `animation.FuncAnimation(func)` requires a function that has an iterator to generate new frames of the animation.  By having this you can effectively get rid of the `Class3.dataCount` instance variable and have the animation handle the business of rolling your data.
2. We need to either tell the animation explicitly how long to run so it does not iterate off your data array causing an `IndexError: list out of range`, or wrap the `update_plot()` function in a `try ... except` clause.  Either will work, but since I don't know the end goal of your program, I provided you the semantics for both options.  I imagine if you have real-time data, you may not know the length of the data array for the animation so you may need the later solution, though I personally feel the former is more elegant.

Thanks for the fun challenge!  It was a good distraction from what I should have been doing.

---

```
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick


class Chart3(object):
    def __init__(self, data, maxt=10):
        self.maxt = maxt
        self.data = data
        self.result = data[:self.maxt]

        # Parse the data columns
        self.tdata = [r[0] for r in self.result]
        self.sdata = [r[4] for r in self.result]
        self.mdata = [r[3] for r in self.result]

        # Initialize plot frame
        xfmt = DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
        self.ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
        self.ax.xaxis_date()
        plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, horizontalalignment='center')
        self.animate()

    def plot(self):
        if len(self.tdata) > self.maxt:  # roll the arrays
            self.tdata = self.tdata[-self.maxt:]
            self.sdata = self.sdata[-self.maxt:]
            self.mdata = self.mdata[-self.maxt:]
            self.result = self.result[-self.maxt:]

        # Plot the next set of line data
        line_min = Line2D(self.tdata, self.sdata, color='r')
        self.ax.add_line(line_min)
        line_max = Line2D(self.tdata, self.mdata, color='g')
        self.ax.add_line(line_max)

        # Plot the next set of candlestick data
        candlestick(self.ax, self.result, width=60 / 86400.0,  colorup='g', colordown='r')

        # Update the x-axis time date and limits
        if len(self.tdata) > 1:
            self.ax.set_xlim(self.tdata[0], self.tdata[-1])

        # Update the y-axis limits
        self.ax.set_ylim(min(self.sdata) * 0.99, max(self.mdata) * 1.01)

    def update_prices(self, cnt):
        """
        adds a data point from data to result list for plotting
        @return:
        """
        results = self.data[self.maxt + cnt]  # add another point of data
        t = (results[0])
        if self.tdata[-1] != t:
            trade = results
            self.result.append([t, trade[1], trade[2], trade[3], trade[4], trade[5], trade[6]])
            self.tdata.append(self.result[-1][0])
            self.sdata.append(self.result[-1][4])
            self.mdata.append(self.result[-1][3])

    def update_plot(self, i):
        try:
            self.update_prices(cnt=i)
            self.plot()
        except:
            pass

    def animate(self):
        # With try ... except in update_plot()
        # anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig=self.fig, func=self.update_plot, interval=1000)

        # Without try ... except in update_plot()
        anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig=self.fig, func=self.update_plot, interval=1000,
                                       frames=len(self.data)-self.maxt, repeat=False)
        plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    testData = [
        [735265.79166666663, 21.901, 21.901, 21.901, 21.901, 21.901, 0],
        [735265.79305555555, 21.901, 21.901, 21.901, 21.901, 21.901, 0],
        [735265.79236111115, 21.901, 21.901, 21.901, 21.901, 21.901, 0],
        [735265.79374999995, 21.9, 21.901, 21.901, 21.9, 21.9005, 11.65],
        [735265.79444444447, 21.901, 21.939, 21.939, 21.901, 21.91525, 23.23606],
        [735265.79513888888, 21.94, 21.95, 21.9703, 21.94, 21.953781250000002, 172.91374199999998],
        [735265.79583333328, 21.96, 21.99, 21.99, 21.96, 21.973333333333336, 142.974981],
        [735265.7965277778, 21.995, 21.995, 21.997, 21.995, 21.995533333333338, 36.541180000000004],
        [735265.7972222222, 21.9703, 21.995, 22.0, 21.9703, 21.993162500000004, 18.305711],
        [735265.79791666672, 21.9999, 21.86, 22.0, 21.86, 21.93492, 103.2468273],
        [735265.79861111112, 21.9045, 21.9045, 21.9045, 21.9045, 21.9045, 2.43879],
        [735265.79930555553, 21.929, 21.861, 21.99, 21.86, 21.92566666666666, 2.838343],
        [735265.80000000005, 21.9241, 21.899, 21.9241, 21.899, 21.907366666666665, 10.0],
        [735265.80069444445, 21.861, 21.86, 21.861, 21.86, 21.860888888888887, 111.367172],
        [735265.80138888885, 21.86, 21.861, 21.861, 21.86, 21.8604, 78.36582],
        [735265.80208333337, 21.861, 21.862, 21.862, 21.859, 21.860483333333335, 112.842532],
        [735265.80277777778, 21.862, 21.863, 21.88, 21.862, 21.8694, 83.64361899999999],
        [735265.80347222218, 21.88, 21.88, 21.88, 21.88, 21.88, 7.46027],
        [735265.8041666667, 21.88, 21.9256, 21.9256, 21.88, 21.9104, 7.06897],
        [735265.8048611111, 21.9256, 21.9256, 21.9256, 21.9256, 21.9256, 0.339032],
        [735265.8055555555, 21.9256, 21.9256, 21.9256, 21.9256, 21.9256, 2.024438],
        [735265.80625000002, 21.88, 21.88, 21.881, 21.88, 21.880249999999997, 25.00003],
        [735265.80694444443, 21.92, 21.92, 21.92, 21.92, 21.92, 0],
        [735265.80763888895, 21.92, 21.92, 21.92, 21.92, 21.92, 0],
        [735265.80833333335, 21.91, 21.92, 21.92, 21.91, 21.915, 80.0],
        [735265.80902777775, 21.881, 21.92, 21.92, 21.881, 21.907, 43.913890200000004],
        [735265.80972222227, 21.914, 22.0, 22.0, 21.914, 21.973115625, 368.000066],
        [735265.81041666667, 21.93, 21.93, 21.93, 21.93, 21.93, 0],
        [735265.81111111108, 21.9, 21.93, 21.93, 21.9, 21.9225, 15.475088999999999],
        [735265.8118055556, 21.93, 22.0, 22.0, 21.91, 21.97401, 56.620048589999996]
    ]

    chart = Chart3(data=testData)
```